# Pyspark: how to reserve only an RDD for each key according to the value

Tags: python, apache-spark

When I join two rdds, each `key` may has multiple `rdd`, here I want to reserve only one rdd for each key. For exmaples.

```
a = sc.parallelize([('a','20200621'), ('b','20200701')])
b = sc.parallelize([('a',('20200520',10)), ('a', ('20200620',20)), ('b', ('20200620', 30))])
a.join(b).collect()

[('b', ('20200701', ('20200620', 30))),
 ('a', ('20200621', ('20200520', 10))),
 ('a', ('20200621', ('20200620', 20)))]
```

I only want to reserve the rdd which the two dates is most closest. Here, in key `a`, `20200621` and `20200620` is closer than `20200621` and `20200520`, so I want to reserve `('a', ('20200621', ('20200620', 20)))` instead of `('a', ('20200621', ('20200520', 10)))`.

The expected result is like:

```
[('b', ('20200701', ('20200620', 30))),
 ('a', ('20200621', ('20200620', 20)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `reduceByKey`.

```
b.join(a).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x if x[1][0][0] > y[1][0][0] else y).collect()
```

Output:

```
[('b', (('20200620', 30), '20200701')), ('a', (('20200620', 20), '20200621'))]
```